# I need to concatenate string with new line

Tags: php

I have string

```
 $st1="string 1"; $str2="string 2"; $str="string 3";
```

I need to make a above strings like this

```
$data='string 1
       string 2
       string 3';
```

i tried string concatenation

```
$data=$str1 . $str2 . $str3;
```

But I get output like this

```
$data = 'string 1 string 2 string 3;
```

any other method is there to get output like above?

Comment: use `PHP_EOL` like this, `$data=$str1 .PHP_EOL. $str2 .PHP_EOL. $str3;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use as below :

`$data=$str1 ."<br>". $str2 ."<br>". $str3;`

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = "{$str1}\n{$str2}\n{$str3}";
```

\n (in "") is a symbol of newline

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data= $str1."<br/>".$str2."<br/>".$str3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br />` tag line break

```
$dta=$str1 . '<br />' .  $str2. '<br />' . $str3;
```